# Transferring user entered data from an Excel worksheet to a Python Script

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm writing a script and I would like to be able to interact with MS Excel. Once I run the script, I would like to open up an excel worksheet, have the user enter some data, do some basic calcs in excel, and then return the calculated data and some of the user entered data to the script.

I'm doing this because I'd like to allow the user to enter all the data at once and not have to answer prompt after prompt and also because I'm new to Python and not even close to being able to write a GUI.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Table 1 (range1 in an Excel worksheet):

User enters Fraction and xa:aa data and excel calculates the blend. Blend info on xa:aa is returned to my python script is used in my script for further calculations. The data entry table is actually longer (more rows of data entry) but just showing enough of a subset to give a feel for what I'm trying to do:

```
Stream       1   2    3  4  5   Blend
Fraction    10% 60% 20% 10       100%
xa          100 150 175 57       135.0
yg          30.7 22 18  12.2     25.6
aa          210 425 375 307      352.2
```

Table 2 (range2 in the same Excel worksheet)

User enters all data and everything is returned to script for further calculations:

```
        Min Max Incr            
temp    45  60  5           
press   7.2 7.8 0.2         
cf      1   5   1
```

Once the data is entered into excel and transferred to the script, I complete the script.

How do I go about doing this ? Excel seems like the easiest way to set up table entry data but if there is another way, please let me know. If it is Excel, how do I go about doing this ?

Comment: Does it need to be interactive, i.e., script does things, then excel, script does more things?  Or is it enough for the script to read an excel file as input?

Comment: Just a bit interactive. Start the script and read a few lines, open Excel and allow user to enter the data, send the data back to the script. The user might want to revise the entered Excel data and rerun.

Another option might be for the user to open the Excel worksheet, enter the data, and then have Excel open the script and read the data. 

I'm not locked into Excel if there is a better way. But I don't think I'm close to ready to develop a GUI in Python yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

Maybe you should look into VBA that way you can make your script in the excel document.

You could also start learning Tkinter, so you make the interface in python right away.

Personally I would do it in HTML. That way you can easy create an interface with inputs, and let javascript do the calculations.

But back to Python and EXCEL.

You could save the document as csv semicolon delimited.

```
import os
with open('yourcsv.csv','r') as f:
    contents = f.read().splitlines()

values = []

for row in range(0,len(contents),1): 
    values += contents[row].split(';')
```

Now you got your table in a multidimensional list.
Do some calculations.

now you need to append the result as a ; delimeted string to the csv file, with some kind of for loop

```
file = open('yourcsv.csv','a')
file.write(results)
file.close()
```

If you want to try with HTML and javascript, it would look something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Optional</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script>
        function calc(){
            var val1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('value1').value);
            var val2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('value2').value);
            var res = val1+val2;
            var resDiv = document.getElementById('result');
            resDiv.innerHTML = parseFloat(res,2);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' id='value1'>
        <input type='text' id='value2'>
        <br>
        <button onClick='calc()'>Calculate</Button>
        <br>
        <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL3PHANTEN/WrdGM/10/)

So you give the html elements id's, then you can acsess them from javascript.

You can also have javascript in a seperate .js file.

Then you just need to refer to it inside the script tag.

```
<script src='yourScript.js'></script>
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting further on the HTML idea. OK, I could easily convert the input table to HTML. The only calculations I'm doing in Excel are coming up with the final blend composition. Blend fraction is simply the sum of the individual fractions. And the xa :aa blend values are just the average of the blends xa[1]*fraction[1] +xa[2]*fraction[2] ...etc.

How do I call HTML from my script ?
Where do I paste the HTML ?
How do I refer the the input variables in my script ? 
Where does the JScript calc live ?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you copy the latest code into a text document, save it as html, open it with chrome. Then you can fiddle with it. Javascript is within the scripttags. Html elements within the html tags. You acsees them by giving them id's.

Comment: Paste the HTML inside main or what ? if __name__ == '__main__': 

When I do that I get an invalid syntax. Do I need to import anything ?  

I used TABLEIZER to create HTML code for the table but not sure what to do next.

Comment: this is not python. Just HTML. paste it into a document, save it as html. And open it in chrome as a webpage.

Comment: Once open in Chrome, where is the interaction with Python ? How would I send the result of the calculations to my script ? What is the sequence here ? Open Chrome, run calcs, then the user goes and opens the .py file, then somehow the data is transferred ?

Ideal would be run the script, the script opens chrome, the user enters the data, the data flows back to the script and the script continues.

Comment: There is no python involved. only javaScript. You do all the calculations in javaScript with this example. If you want to send data to python, you should look into a python module called Flask.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential approach using pandas.  If the input file doesn't exist, it writes a dummy file (modify this to suit), then opens the excel file, and reads back into a dataframe once the user has closed.  Replace `excel_path` with a path to your Excel install (I'm using LibreOffice to here).

```
import os
import subprocess

import pandas as pd

input_file = 'input.xlsx'
excel_path = 'soffice'

#############
# setup stuff
#############

if not os.path.isfile(input_file):
    input_template = pd.DataFrame(columns=['1','2','3','4'])
    # any additional code to set up space for user to input values

    input_template.to_excel(input_file)
else:

# call excel and open the input file
subprocess.call([excel_path, input_file])

# read modified input into DataFrame
excel_input = pd.read_excel(input_file)

################
# body of script
################
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: On which line? Make sure the `input_file` is a path you have write access to.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [xlwings](http://xlwings.org), a library I wrote to do exactly what you want.